# Number of Min Heaps possible?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, heap

The number of possible min-heaps containing each value from {1,1,1,1,1,1,1} exactly once is ?

=====================================================================

If the question would have been The number of possible min-heaps containing each value from {1,2,3,4,5,6,7} exactly once is ?

Then the answer is 80 and I know, how to solve it, but how to deal with when all values are same?

Comment: If elements are not distinguishable - number is 1, isn't it?

Comment: @MBo Yes, seems like it, there's only one Min Heap possible? So, can we say we get an unique Min/Max heap when all elements are same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main property of heap is that the structure of the heap always remains same, only the values of the node change.

Here we only have one distinct element and all nodes have same value. So the answer is 1.

> So, can we say we get an unique Min/Max heap when all elements are same?

Yes, as there is only one heap possible.

Answer (score 1):

When elements are not distinguishable, then only one heap exists.

*For completeness*: If heap elements contain secondary keys, we can say that number of different heaps might be at most n! (for all different secondary keys)